# Filter out data with best combinations within two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like the below sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['1','1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4','4','5'],
                   'col_2':['A','B','C','A','B','C','D','D','A','A','B'],
                   'col_3':['256','546','985','573','265','731','968','592','364','657','953']})

print(df)  

   col_1 col_2 col_3
0      1     A   256
1      1     B   546
2      1     C   985
3      2     A   573
4      2     B   265
5      3     C   731
6      3     D   968
7      4     D   592
8      4     A   364
9      4     A   657
10     5     B   953
```

I want filter out this data and find out the best combinations of two columns covering each value at least once.

For example in the above data the first combination for 'col_1' and 'col_2' is [1,A] and when we search further the next available combination is [1,B] but it's is giving me only one new value i.e. 'B' as '1' is already covered in the first combination. So we should search further before finalizing the second combination. On searching further we can find a better combination i.e. [2,B] giving us both the new values. This way we can search for further combinations. Whichever combination we pick 'col_3' value should come as it is. The expected output is:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0     1     A   256
1     2     B   265
2     3     C   731
3     4     D   592
4     5     B   953
```

Whatever I tried to filter out this data didn't work for me.

Can anyone provide a solution or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes 'B' is repeated because that is the only combination available for value '5' in col_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.

Here's my working solution which is giving the output as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'],
                   'col_2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
                   'col_3': ['256', '546', '985', '573', '265', '731', '968', '592', '364', '657', '953', '476', '835',
                             '683', '572', '903']})

df = df.dropna()

# the columns to use when calculating scores
COLUMNS = ["col_1", "col_2"]

col_1_set = set()
col_2_set = set()
best_combinations = []
rows = []
ignored_rows = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    combination = row[COLUMNS].values.tolist()

    # Let's check whether we have picked col_1 value or not yet
    if combination[0] in col_1_set:
        # We have already picked col_1 value
        # Let's check the col_2 value status
        if combination[1] in col_2_set:
            # col_2 value has also been picked
            # Let's ignore this combination and continue checking further
            continue
        else:
            # col_2 value is not yet picked but col_1 value has already been picked
            # Since it's not the best combination we will check it later again
            ignored_rows.append(row)
    elif combination[1] in col_2_set:
        # This col_1 value is new for us.
        # But col_2 value has already been picked
        # Since it's not the best combination we will check it later again
        ignored_rows.append(row)
    else:
        # col_value has also not yet picked.
        # Best combination found, Let's store it
        best_combinations.append(combination)
        col_1_set.add(combination[0])
        col_2_set.add(combination[1])
        rows.append(row)

# Now Let's check for the ignored combinations
for ignored_row in ignored_rows:
    ignored_combination = ignored_row[COLUMNS].values.tolist()
    if not (ignored_combination[0] in col_1_set) or not (ignored_combination[1] in col_2_set):
        # Either of the elements within the above combination is missed by us
        # Let's add it
        best_combinations.append(ignored_combination)
        col_1_set.add(ignored_combination[0])
        col_2_set.add(ignored_combination[1])
        rows.append(ignored_row)

df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(rows).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_filtered)
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0     1     A   256
1     2     B   265
2     3     C   731
3     4     D   592
4     5     E   476
5     5     F   835
6     5     G   683
7     5     H   572
8     5     I   903
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to achieve this is with an iterative algorithm.

First, you need to extract columns, then you define a `get_score` function to understand how much value a combination has, given an history of combinations already set as valuable.

Last, you append either combinations that are good (`score == MAX_SCORE`) or the last combination, as in your example (`i == last_index`).

In the end you will obtain a list of combinations (or tuples), that you can easily cast back to a `DataFrame`.

```py
# define max score of a combination
MAX_SCORE = 2

# extract columns as lists
x, y = df.col_1.to_list(), df.col_2.to_list()

# function to compute score
def get_score(combination, old_combinations):
    x, y = combination
    if not old_combinations:
        return MAX_SCORE
    
    # split a list of two-sized tuples in two lists 
    xs, ys = [*zip(*old_combinations)]
    score = MAX_SCORE
    if x in xs:
        score -= 1
    if y in ys:
        score -= 1
    return score


# get list of pairs
iterator = list(zip(x, y))
last_index = len(iterator) - 1
combinations = []

# algorithm
for i, combination in enumerate(iterator):
    score = get_score( combination, combinations )
    if score == MAX_SCORE or i == last_index:
        combinations.append( combination )

# result
combinations  # [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D'), (5, 'B')]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(combinations, columns=["col_1", "col_2"])
print(new_df)
```

This prints the following:

```py
   col_1 col_2
0      1     A
1      2     B
2      3     C
3      4     D
4      5     B
```

EDIT:
In general, if you have `N` columns but want to calculate the scores only on `M` columns (with `N <= M`), you can generalize the algorithm as follows:

```py
# the columns to use when calculating scores
COLUMNS = ["col_1", "col_2"]

# if no columns is provided, use every column
if not COLUMNS:
    COLUMNS = df.columns.to_list()

# check non-empty columns
assert COLUMNS

# check valid columns
assert all(col in df.columns for col in COLUMNS)

MAX_SCORE = len(COLUMNS)

def get_score(combination, combinations) -> int:
    if not combinations:
        return MAX_SCORE

    score = MAX_SCORE
    for i, value in enumerate(combination):
        if value in [c[i] for c in combinations]:
            score -= 1

    return score

last_index = len(df) - 1
combinations = []
rows = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    combination = row[COLUMNS].values.tolist()
    score = get_score(combination, combinations)
    if score == MAX_SCORE or i == last_index:
        combinations.append(combination)
        rows.append(row)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows).reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
```

This prints the following:

```py
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0     1     A   256
1     2     B   265
2     3     C   731
3     4     D   592
4     5     B   953
```

Comment: Could you please tell me, what is **combinations** variable in your code? I tried using **from itertools import combinations** but your code didn't work with that import.

Comment: A `combination` is the tuple (number, letter), one for each row. You can use my code right away if your dataframe is called `df`, without any additional import.

Comment: @prem I see what you meant, `combinations` was an empty list and was missing from the code, now it's fixed

Comment: Thanks your code is working now but the problem is there are many more columns in my actual dataframe and it is returning only the two columns in the output. I want rest of the columns also for the combination picked. Do you have any idea how to get this output with all the other columns?

Comment: I have updated the question also with an additional column, please check if you can help.

Comment: @prem this is now generic for a dataframe with `n` columns

Comment: Thanks again for your answer to handle N columns scenario but where can I pass the two column names which must be used for filtration as these two can be on any positions within the N columns?

Comment: @prem Now that's more clear, this should be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks it's working good for the current sample data but when I tested it with actual data the output was not as expected. Then I tried to increase the sample data size and the output was wrong. You can also try the same, just increase five times '5' in col_1 and  add 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' in col_2. In the output you will find that combination for 'F', 'G', 'H' are missing.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for your help. Since I am new to python, your code helped me to implement the logic for this problem. I have posted the working code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Iteratively adding pairs while using groupby to count the available unused options, commented inline for clarity. Superior to other iterative approaches as the loop has finishes in max `df['col_2'].nunique()` iterations, possibly faster.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 4, 8: 4, 9: 4, 10: 5},
    'col_2': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'C', 6: 'D', 7: 'D', 8: 'A', 9: 'A', 10: 'B'},
})
pairs = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

# Iterate and get all col_1, col_2 pair such that the combination is optimal
# - col_2 not yet in pairs
# - col_1 associated uniquely (or minimally) to that col_2, once previous combinations were removed
while len(df[~df['col_2'].isin(pairs['col_2'])]):
    options = df[~df['col_2'].isin(pairs['col_2'])].groupby('col_1')['col_2'].unique()
    n_options = options.str.len()
    if n_options.eq(1).any():
        add = options.index[n_options.eq(1)]
    else:
        add = [n_options.idxmin()]
    pairs = pairs.append(options[add].reset_index().explode('col_2'), ignore_index=True)

# Now all possible col_2 are in pairs, add missing col_1 with any col_2
pairs = pairs.append(df[~df['col_1'].isin(pairs['col_1'])].drop_duplicates('col_1'), ignore_index=True)

print(pairs)
```

This returns the following:

```
  col_1 col_2
0     5     B
1     2     A
2     1     C
3     4     D
4     3     C
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not giving the required output and the order is also different.

Comment: @prem This answer selects the best pairs every time, e.g. start with (5, B) as 5 is only ever associated with B. That means that it will always give you the shortest possible number of pairs in the output. Regardless I’ve added another answer that does as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.pivot(columns='col_2', values='col_1')
desired_df = []
last_uniques = []
for col in df.columns:
    uniques = df[col].dropna().unique()
    desired = list(set(uniques) - set(last_uniques))
    desired_df.append({'col_1': desired[0], 'col_2': col})
    last_uniques.append(desired[0])

for col in df.columns:
    uniques = list(set(df[col].dropna()) - set(last_uniques))
    if uniques:
        desired_df.append({'col_1': uniques[0], 'col_2': col})
        last_uniques.append(uniques[0])

df_final = pd.DataFrame(data=desired_df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   col_1 col_2
0      1     A
1      2     B
2      3     C
3      4     D
4      5     B
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but  but this is not giving the required output and the order is also different.

Answer (score 0):

You can first add iteratively as required − your desired output leaves no other way than to use a loop:

```
>>> use = df.iloc[[0]]
>>> while True:
...   mask = df['col_1'].isin(use['col_1']) | df['col_2'].isin(use['col_2'])
...   if mask.all():
...     break
...   use = use.append(df[~mask].iloc[0], ignore_index=True)
... 
>>> use
   col_1 col_2  col_3
0      1     A    256
1      2     B    265
2      3     C    731
3      4     D    592
```

Then we need to add in rows with missing values in either column:

```
>>> miss_1 = df.groupby('col_1', as_index=False).first()
>>> miss_2 = df.groupby('col_2', as_index=False).first()
>>> use = use.append(miss_1[~miss_1['col_1'].isin(use['col_1'])], ignore_index=True)
>>> use = use.append(miss_2[~miss_2['col_2'].isin(use['col_2'])], ignore_index=True)
>>> use
   col_1 col_2  col_3
0      1     A    256
1      2     B    265
2      3     C    731
3      4     D    592
4      5     B    953
```

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Though your code works fine on the sample data, it gets stuck within the while loop with actual data.